# What is faster LAG(column) or saving in a variable the last value of a cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically what the question says. I have this sql

```
select 
LAG(ID_ESTADO) over(order by ID_EXPEDIENTE,orden) ULTIMO_IDESTADO,
LAG(ID_EXPEDIENTE) over(order by ID_EXPEDIENTE,orden) ULTIMO_EXPEDIENTE,
LAG(TABLA) over(partition by ID_EXPEDIENTE order by orden) ULTIMA_TABLA,
LAG(TIPO_ESTADO) over(partition by ID_EXPEDIENTE order by orden) ULTIMO_ESTADO,
LAG(FECHA_ESTADO) over(partition by ID_EXPEDIENTE order by orden) ULTIMA_FECHA,
LAG(ID_EXPEDIENTE,2) over(order by ID_EXPEDIENTE,orden) INMANT_EXPEDIENTE,
LAG(TABLA,2) over(partition by ID_EXPEDIENTE order by orden) INMANT_TABLA,
LAG(TIPO_ESTADO,2) over(partition by ID_EXPEDIENTE order by orden) INMANT_ESTADO,
ID_ESTADO,
ID_EXPEDIENTE,
TABLA,
TIPO_ESTADO,
orden,
anio,
fecha_estado,
NUMERO_EXPEDIENTE,
ANIO_EXPEDIENTE,
NATURALEZA_EXPEDIENTE, 
ID_OFICINA,
DESCRIPCION,
ID_TIPO_INSTANCIA, 
ID_OBJETO_JUICIO,
DESC_OBJETO_JUICIO,
FECHA_INICIO,
ID_EXPEDIENTE_ORIGEN,
CARATULA_EXPEDIENTE
from EST_ESTADOS_CIVIL e where TABLA like 'R%' and ANIO between 2012 and 
2016
```

I wanted to know what is faster if to compare values in a cursor like this with lets say TIPO_ESTADO = ULTIMO_ESTADO

or to use the query alone and get the LAG values from variables and comparing them.

Bear in mind that changing this changes my query from 280.000 or so rows to 3 million rows.

I can keep the 280.000 rows but i need at least to include one or two LAG columns

Comment: Your question is equivalent to the following (unless I am missing something): Am I better off implementing my own version of LAG() by using a cursor, etc., or is the Oracle native implementation better? (My opinion of the right answer to this question is intentionally not included here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all questions about performance, you can test the code to see which is better.

As for my opinion, I would not even consider using a cursor for performance.  Set-based operations in the data should be better.

Note:  If you do use a cursor, you will need an `order by`, which will probably pretty much kill any expected performance gains that you might think that you would get.